# catkin_make: Could NOT find SDL

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-melodic, catkin-make, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to use catkin_make, it fails at map_server.

I got the following message

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find SDL (missing: SDL_LIBRARY SDL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindSDL.cmake:190 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  navigation/map_server/CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ryosukeo/practice_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ryosukeo/practice_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:4688: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

What do I do to solve this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340655/catkin_make:-could-not-find-sdl/) by [ryosukeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/50497/ryosukeo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-12-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev` and

`sudo apt-get install libsdl-dev`

These solve the issue.

[Source](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/579)

Also for melodic, you can use this to install other dependencies too. Enter your `practice_ws` directory and run this command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic -y
```

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2019-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryosukeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/50497/ryosukeo/) on 2019-12-27**:
Thank you.
this problem solved.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2019-12-27**:
Then you can accept the answer as correct ( the tick mark is on the left of the answer, under the voting area)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-27**:
Related: #q252478.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2019-12-27**:
Also, about your own packages, do not forget to add your dependencies to your `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`. I've seen lots of packages which they don't have all dependencies listed. `rosdep` looks up for dependencies from your definitions in the package. Even if you are able to build your workspace, you might face with a runtime error when a dependent package isn't installed.